# Is there a name for the property of a function that maps the empty set to zero?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, soft-question, notation, definition

We almost can define a measure in a concise and neat way by stating that a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ is a countably additive function $ \mu : \Sigma \to [0, \infty] $ such that $ \mu(\emptyset) = 0 $. Except for the last property that I couldn't find a name for.

On my mind, such an essential should be given a name.

So far the best I could come up with is to call $\mu$ an *empty-to-zero* function.

References and ideas are welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't naming the property take longer to say than '$\mu(\emptyset)$ = 0'?

Comment: Doesn't additivity (vacuously) implies that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$?

Comment: There are many different kinds of functions which do, perhaps that's why you can't find it. For example, a surjective increasing function $f:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to [0,\infty]$ sends the minimum element ($\varnothing$) to the minimum element $(0)$ (Since $\varnothing\subseteq A$ for all $A$, then $f(\varnothing)\leq f(A)$ for every $A$. Since $f$ is surjective, you get the result).

Comment: @KyleGannon Yes... That's a point. I don't see why not.

Comment: @user275313 This is a great workaround! If we define the union of the empty set to be itself and the sum of the empty set to be 0, then it would imply.

Comment: @KyleGannon There's also the point of explaining mathematics verbally. Saying "mu is a _____ function" is less verbose than saying "mu is a function that maps zero to the empty set".

Comment: It's not ordinary. It's fundamental, but it's also very common.

Comment: I think it doesn't have a name because it's such an obviously desirable property that it may be forgotten to be even mentioned, although it's necessary in order to ensure that at least one measurable set has non-infinite measure.

Comment: @JonathanZ, what if $\mu(A) = \infty$ for each $A$?  This is still countably additive, but the definition would yield $\mu(\phi) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, @fourierwho, I don't understand how that follows. Did you see my answer below and the follow-up comments? I think they might relate to your example.

Comment: I meant "the definition would yield $\mu(\phi) = \infty$."  You need "finite somewhere," as in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additivity implies $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

$$\mu(\emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset \cup \emptyset) = \mu(\emptyset) +\mu(\emptyset) = 2 \mu(\emptyset), $$

with the second equality allowed because $\emptyset \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

It's all because of the weird properties of the empty set, so I think we include it to make the definition easier to think about, although it's not logically required.

Edit: Oops, $\mu(\emptyset)$ could also be $+\infty$ and satisfy that equation. I guess my argument doesn't work, though you could require "finite somewhere" and it would end up being equivalent to $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, though it wouldn't be obvious.

Comment: Just to be super-clear: 'finite measure' usually means that no set has infinite measure, while this argument will work so long as there is at least one set with non-infinite measure. So, while we can't just remove the '$\mu(\emptyset) = 0$' condition, we can replace it with with the condition "there is at least one set with with finite measure",which sounds weaker but turns out to be equivalent. I'd almost be willing to use the phrase 'non-trivial' to describe that. It's not very precise, but it sounds good.

Comment: I am accepting this answer not only for its content but also for @JonathanZ's contribution in the question comments section; mainly for the comment about the vacuous implication.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the definition of countable additivity.

Countable addivity applies to any countable collection of disjoint sets — in particular, it applies collections of size *zero*.

The union of a collection of sets of size zero is $\varnothing$, and the sum of a collection of numbers of size zero is $0$. Therefore, $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$.

---

Note that the above argument would not apply if you only assume addivity for countably *infinite* collections of sets, which is a weird thing to do, but it seems some really do use "countable additivity" in this more restrictive sense.

In this case, you can also invoke finite additivity (to which the above argument does apply), so that you have additivity for all countable cardinalities.

Comment: Thanks for your time but this has already been discussed in the comments section of the question.

Comment: @mucciolo: Yes, but answers are supposed to go in answers rather than in comments.